# C# (WPF) Casting UIElement into an Type of class without knowing the type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, dependency-properties

I would like to cast an UIElement to a Type of class the generic way, because I don't know what kinds of UIElements are given.

*Example:*
I have some UserControls, let's say UC1 and UC2.
Now I have a method that have to check a property from these controls. The propery is a dependecy property so UIElement doesn't know about it.

I know, I can do easily like that:

```
var _uc1prop = ((UC1)my_ui_element).MyProperty;
var _uc2prop = ((UC2)my_ui_element).MyPoperty;
```

That's easy to build in a switch/case, but I'm searching for a solution where I don't have to know what kind of Type the object is from.

Something like this *( I know that this doesn't work! )*

```
Type t = my_ui_element.GetType();
var _ucprop = my_ui_element.Cast<t>().MyProperty;
```

or

```
var _ucprop = (my_ui_element as t).MyProperty
```

The reason I'm searching for something like this is that in future I could have some new UserControls that have to be processed by the method and I don't want to expand the method any time.

I hope it's understandable, othwerwise let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Implement a common Interface in all your own UserControls for that that surfaces the "MyProperty" property for example.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. That's the half way to a solution. Now I have the property visible attached on the UIElement in inspector window. But code sight says: "property doesn't exists"

Comment: You casted the Control to the interface to access the property?

Comment: Of course not :-) Mentally deranged, apparently. THANK YOU, that works perfectly and is a simple and logical solution, I think!